# How to find out if enviroment variable is not set?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, environment-variables

So I try

```
char buffer[1000];
GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",(char*)&buffer,sizeof(buffer));
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

to check if it exists but I do not see how to see if its empty? And It couts some really bad output=(

Comment: Suggestion: you don't need that cast on `buffer`

Comment: @Marlon - that cast is actually hiding his error.  He's passing `&buffer` when he should be passing `buffer` to GetEnvironmentVariable.  That's why he gets garbage output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN has this to say about `GetEnvironmentVariable`:

> If the function fails, the return value is zero. If the specified environment variable was not found in the environment block, GetLastError returns ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND.

(Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188.aspx)

So I guess you should test the function's return value:

```
char buffer[1000];
if(GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", buffer, sizeof(buffer)))
{
    // non-zero, go ahead!
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
else
{
    // zero, something went wrong
}
```

Comment: but how to check if ounput is "zero"?

Comment: @Kabumbus: I'm not trying to be a prick, but if you don't know how to check a function's return value you need to stop whatever you're doing and start reading a C++ book for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `getenv` which returns null if the variable doesn't exist and a blank string if it's blank.

Answer (score 0):

When the environment variable is not set GetEnvironmentVariable returns 0 and GetLastError() returns ERROR_ENVVAR_NOT_FOUND (203).

Have a look at the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx